# Unable to change TextInputLayout hint gravity programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, material-components, textinputlayout

[image]

**XML #1** - TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:hint="Enter your email"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**XML #2** - Only a simple TextInputEditText (not wrapped in TextInputLayout):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/inputTextField"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

All I want to do is change the gravity of the hint in the TextInputLayout to be start|top **programmatically**.

The 'programmatically' part is important because I'm reusing this TextInputLayout+TextInputEditText for multiple use-cases which require different positions of the hint text.

In case of XML #1, the hint stays there as the following 2 lines don't work:

### Activity code:

```
    inputTextField.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
    textInputLayout.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
```

In case of XML #2, this works perfectly and the hint moves to the top:

### Activity code:

```
    inputTextField.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
```

Why doesn't the hint move programmatically for XML #1?

### Desired Result:

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the layout you can use `android:gravity="top"` in the `TextInputEditText`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:gravity="top"
        ..>
```

Programmatically you can use:

```
textinputlayout.getEditText().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

[image]

It requires at least the version [**`1.2.0-alpha06`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/a040af5bd3a4e429f5d1323e72519e002ef4f4bb).

A final note.
With a `FilledBox` style currently it works only adding `android:minLines` to 2 or greater to the `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to material 1.2.0-alpha05 did the trick! Never assumed that the issue could be in the library itself.

Here's the fixed issue link on the material library repo: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/933

Comment: It must also be set TextInputEditText inputType 'none' or 'textMultiLine' to achive the expected behaviour.